# Excel xlookup formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to come up with a formula that will yield the position of two criteria. Per below, looking for Product B from column A and then the position of the first non-zero value. In this case, the answer would be D2.

I tried a combination of xlookup and then index/match to no avail. Any help will be much appreciated.

[image: snap]

Answer (score 1):

If the list of products is in `G1` you can use a formula:

```
=ADDRESS(MATCH(G1,$A$1:$A$4,0),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX($B$1:$E$4,MATCH(G1,$A$1:$A$4,0),0)>0,0)+1,4)
```

[image: First positive]

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to accomplish the desired output:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G1</kbd>

```
=ADDRESS(XMATCH(G1,A1:A4),XMATCH(1,SIGN(FILTER(B1:E4,A1:A4=G1)))+1,4)
```

---

If you have access to `LET()` function then we can make it shorter be reducing the repeating ranges using variables:

```
=LET(α, G1, δ, A1:A4, ADDRESS(XMATCH(α,δ),XMATCH(1,SIGN(FILTER(B1:E4,δ=α)))+1,4))
```

---

- Using the first `XMATCH()` in the `ADDRESS()` function we are getting the **row_num**
- Using `FILTER()` function based on `G1` getting the respective values, next wrapping within `SIGN()` function to return the sign of a number. Once it returns using `XMATCH()` to return the position again which gives the **column_num**
- Last parameter used is `4` in `ADDRESS()` function to get the `Relative` value and which returns as `D2` for the example.

---

Comment: Thank you both for the incredible help here. I removed address from the string as i realized I was looking for an average of 6 numbers following the first non zero value and it worked to perfection. Much appreciated